# win7 rails aptana studio 3 + rmagick + bundler cannot start debug server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana, bundler, rmagick, gemfile

i've been trying to start 'debug server' for a rails application in aptana studio 3 but i never succeeded.
every time i tried to start debug server, exception thrown: Uncaught exception: Could not load the bundler gem. Install it with `gem install bundler`.

1. i followed the aptana studio 3 getting started guide and installed everything except rvm (i don't know how to install it on windows). is it really necessary for aptana studion 3 on windows? i have only 1 ruby version installed.
2. i installed rmagick successfully and i put 'require rubygems' and 'require RMagick' in preinitializer.rb. am i putting them at the right place?
3. i use bundler for gem management and i can successfully start the server by running "ruby script/server". i just don't know what's wrong with the debug environment. am i missing some PATH setting?
4. any body running smooth with aptana studio 3, rmagick and bundler. can tell me your settings?

thx.

windows 7 prof 64bit
aptana studio 3
ruby 1.8.7
rails 2.3.14
ruby-debug-base 0.10.4
ruby-debug-ide 0.4.16
rmagick 2.12.0 (C:\Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32)
imagemagick (C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.5.6-Q8)
bundler 1.0.18 gemfile (gem "rmagick", "2.12.0")
preinitializer.rb
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'RMagick'
  require 'bundler'

batterhead

Answer (score 0):

Ah found the problem.  The environment needs to have a ‘MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH’ variable added that points to your ImageMagick modules/coders installation path.  You can add this in the "Environment" tab of your debug configuration for the project.